# Using different packages for Controllers when using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

If I create a standard Spring project in the spring toolkit it works great!

I visit `localhost:8080/greeting` and get my `hello world` response.

If I copy those 2 files into another package in my source tree and then visit `localhost:8080/greeting` I get a :

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> ```
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
> Fri Oct 17 18:15:45 BST 2014
> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
> ```

Moving the 3 classes into the same default package fixes the problem but from a source tree organization perspective, this is not what I want to do.

I expect this to be due to some auto-configuration so please can somebody tell me what I have to do to allow my project to support multiple packages as controllers and objects.

Comment: Did you recompile and redeploy the new code?  Did Tomcat do a hot redeploy? It doesn't show up by magic.

Comment: Well I am using the spring tool suite and I right clicked my project and did run as -> Spring boot app. This may not force a recompile but eclipse will almost always compile as changes are made directly? Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If your code looks like in [this](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-beginner-tutorial-with-spring-tool-suite-ide#SpringMVCConfiguration) tutorial, then
Open `servlet-context.xml`and change

```
<context:component-scan base-package="..."/>
```

You can list multiple packages. Use comma as separator.

**Update:**

That was for XML-based configuration.

If you create "Spring Boot App", then configuration is annotation-based. In this case you need to search for classes annotated with `@ComponentScan`. Typically it is a main class or class called AppConfig.

By default it searches recursively controllers and other components starting from the class' package. You can add parameters to this annotation like this:

```
@ComponentScan({ "x.y.z.services", "x.y.z.controllers" })
```

Comment: Thats the one!! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It was also useful for me!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the main method is in the package called com.setech.app and a controller is in a package called com.setech.controller.

For spring-boot 1.3.x upwards try this by adding "scanBasePackages" like this.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.setech"} )
public class ResttanslatorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(ResttanslatorApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Credit goes to Kamil Wozniak from [here](https://smarterco.de/java-spring-boot-mvc-ontroller-not-called/).

Answer (score 1):

Moving the Springbootapplication(application.java) file to another package resolved the issue for me. Keep it separate from the controllers and repositories. You can use any number of packages and have multiple controllers.But use`@ComponenScan(basePackages={" "," "})` and mention all the packages.